# How do I include pronouns and other types of words in Wordnet?

Tags: ontology, wordnet

I am using Princeton's WordNet for an application, but there is no support for pronouns, conjunctions, and several other types of words within the database. Does anybody know if there is a way to supplement the Wordnet database with these types of words?

Thanks,

Ted

Answer (score 3):

First, they're missing since WordNet only contains the open-class words as described in their page:

> > Q. Why is WordNet missing: of, an, the, and, about, above, because, etc.
> >     A. WordNet only contains "open-class words": nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs. Thus, excluded words include determiners, prepositions, pronouns, conjunctions, and particles.

And so other types of words which do not exist in WordNet are actually closed-class words, in the sense that they have fixed number of entries. Therefore, you can always hardcode them into your program.

You can find the list of pronouns, conjunctions, etc. on [this website](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/word-lists.html).

Comment: I think most of us are looking not for just lists but for definitions, relationships between words, etc.