# why Wordnet dictionary doesn't contain the word 'she'?

Tags: nlp, wordnet

anyone know why wordnet doesn't contain the word 'she'? thanks.

see this [link](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=she&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @PaulR - WordNet is a widely used NLP resource which is accessed programmatically. Knowing whether a pretty popular English pronoun is in a resource is definitely relevant for many of us in NLP! ;)

Comment: thanks for the explaination @amp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this is in the [WordNet FAQ](http://www.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/database/) (which I just discovered existed), and also in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056042/how-do-i-include-pronouns-and-other-types-of-words-in-wordnet).

Basically, `she` is a pronoun - a word that kind of stands in place for a noun. Instead of referring to Betty by her name - which is a proper noun - you may refer to her as `she`.

Pronouns by themselves (without Betty, in this case) don't actually *contain* any meaning. Some people, like the WordNet people, call that kind of word *closed-class words*. By design, WordNet only includes [*open-class words*](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/openclassterm.htm).

From the Wordnet FAQ:

> **Q. Why is WordNet missing: of, an, the, and, about, above, because, etc. [and pronouns]**
>
> A. WordNet only contains "open-class words": nouns, verbs,
> adjectives, and adverbs. Thus, excluded words include determiners,
> prepositions, pronouns, conjunctions, and particles.

Answer (score 0):

Wordnet isn't a standard dictionary, for example, if you search "he" you end up with the element helium and the 5th letter of the hebrew alphabet as definitions. However, you don't end up with the definition of a noun referring to a man.

My best guess is that "she" isn't contained because it doesn't have a definition of a anything other than a noun referring to a woman. I say best guess because I'm not a language expert so I can't definitively say it has no other definitions. If you look up "he" on thefreedictionary.com though it does have references to helium and hebrew. If you look up "she" it only has definitions related to gender.

tl;dr The reason "she" doesn't exist as a word in wordnet is that, by their rules (or whatever you want to call it) it isn't a word.